# Image Hover Overlay - next to each other Horizontally?

Tags: html, css, image, overlay

I have put an image with a hover overlay on my html website, i wanted three of them side by side but when i try to add another it goes underneath the previous one instead of beside it.
I have tried float:left however this messes up the hover overlay.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this code on its own html page, to make sure no other styles are affecting it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Images test</title>
</head>

<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 33.3333%;
    float: left;
}

.image {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .image {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
}

.text {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 32px;
}

</style>

<body>

<h2>AUDIO SHOCK</h2>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i2.wp.com/factschronicle.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Bose-QuietComfort-35-Best-Wireless-Headphones-2017-min.jpg?fit=640%2C380&ssl=1" alt="Headphones" class="image">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">Product Details</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://static.bhphotovideo.com/explora/sites/default/files/styles/960/public/_shure-aonic-50-wireless-headphones_lifestyle-004-16x9.jpg?itok=GpxHyHuY" alt="Other Headphones" class="image">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">Product Details</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://nonstopnewcomer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/headphones-1149205_640.jpg" alt="Other Headphones" class="image">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">Product Details</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them side by side, try

```
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%
}
```

Not sure if you want the images side by side or not, so here's a general tip: 
Some elements have `display: block` by default, and they won't ever be next to each other unless you specify. You can do this using `display: inline-block;` and specifying their width.